# How do tablespaces differ in DB2 from databases in MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Tags: database, db2, ibm

In DB2, it seems there is a strong separation between what a *database* is and what a *tablespace* is. Where as in MySQL and MS SQL Server *tablespace* and *database* seemed to be used synonymously.

What are the differences, if any?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's about inner workings of RDBMSs. It's more suitable for dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DB2 and Oracle, tablespace is roughly the child 'containers' within a database. You can, for example, organize your huge tables to be created on a specific tablespace, for managing the disk storage.

In MS SQL server there is no concept of tablespaces AFAIK. It uses file groups for the purpose of organizing storage and there is no one-to-one correlation with the tablespace concept.